# Replacing Alt with Meta for all Eclipse shortcuts

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Eclipse on Ubuntu. Is there some way to replace Alt with Meta in all shortcuts for my current workspace? Given the file where shortcuts are stored, perhaps I can do some kind of search and replace?

Answer (score 0):

Only the bindings you have defined - marked with "U" in the Keys preference page - are save explicitly. The default bindings are liften from the `org.eclipse.ui.bindings` extension point.

I think you can accomplish what you want by adding a filter (a `Listener`) to the current display. Something like

```
final Listener filter = new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        // Translate event.keyCode
        // Translate event.stateMask
    }
};
Display display = Display.getCurrent();
display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, filter);
display.addFilter(SWT.KeyUp, filter);
```

Comment: Sorry if it's confusing, that was a user rather than programmer question -- I'm trying to find the easiest way to replace my Eclipse shortcuts

Comment: I understand. But you - or somebody else - should be able to implement a plug-in that will do the trick... I'll see if I can find the time later tonight... and an Ubuntu image for VMware so I can test it as well...